# How to validate input format in devextreme textbox?

Tags: .net, regex, model-view-controller, devexpress, devextreme

I have a textbox, and I want to validate the input.
The acceptable format should look like this 123.908-09, but it should accept 52.232-1. This input can be null as well.

*The textbox won't accept 52.232-1*

Model

```
 [RegularExpression(@"([0-9]+.[0-9]+-[0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "X has an invalid format")]
 [DisplayName("X")]
 public string? x{ get; set; }
```

Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddX(string values)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("valud values: " + values);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View

```
     groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.x)
        .Editor(e =>
                e.TextBox()
                .Mask("###.###-####") 
                .MaskRules(new { X = new JS("/[02-9]/") })
                .MaskInvalidMessage("Please follow the standard x format")
                .UseMaskedValue(true)
                );
```

Am I going in the right direction? I added the mask because, when I only added validator in model, users were able to enter letters in the textbox.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})$` helps,
`\d === [0-9]`. And here's a [way to check.](https://regex101.com/r/GCn7rZ/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried it didn't work :(

[RegularExpression(@"(/d{1,3}/./d{1,3}-/d{1,3})", ErrorMessage = "Section has an invalid format")]

Comment: You've used forward slashes. Replace them with backward slashes " \ "

Comment: Hi, it worked thanks. But it still accepts letters. :/

Comment: Hey, Just updated my original answer.
 `^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})$`  should fix it :)